# mysql errorno 150

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables 'member' and 'book' defined as:

```
create table member(

      mem_id bigint(11) unsigned auto_increment not null primary key,
      firstname varchar(20) not null,
      lastname varchar(20) not null,
      gender varchar(1) not null
);

create table book(

      book_id varchar(15) not null primary key,
      isbn varchar(15) not null,
      book_name varchar(100) not null
);
```

Now I want to create follwing table named 'return_book' as:

```
create table return_book(

      mem_id bigint(11) unsigned not null,
      book_id varchar(15) , 
      date date,    
      primary key(mem_id, book_id),
      foreign key(mem_id) references member(mem_id) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
      foreign key(book_id) references book(book_id)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE CASCADE            
);
```

But I always get the following error: "Can't create table return_book "
Please help.

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: Can't create table 'lms.return_book' <errno: 150>

Comment: Check out this. May be this helps you. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,19755,570578#msg-570578

Comment: [It works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0ac6) for me.  What storage engine are you using?

Comment: INNODB. Are you sure it's working?!

Comment: For me it works fine, with your querys. Is there curently any data in a table?

Comment: The problem may be, as Bhavik's comment and link, that the `book` table has different charset with the charset that `return_book` is (tried to be) created.

Comment: @ypercube: Can that be the case if the `CREATE TABLE` statements are exactly as given in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in the column-name 'mem_id' in 'member' table :D! Further, I also learned that referenced column and referencing column must have same types.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error

```
create table return_book(
mem_id bigint(11) unsigned not null,
book_id varchar(15) , 
date date,  
  primary key(mem_id, book_id),
  foreign key(mem_id) references member(mem_id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
  foreign key(book_id) references book(book_id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE CASCADE            
);
```

Comment: OOPs :D! That was a typo in the question!

Comment: Now I have made correction in the question.